# picture isn't saved properly into the database (as BLOB)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, blob, image

I try to save a picture into the database as a BLOB, but its not stored properly in the database.

The byte[] which is passed is correct and has 4300 characters and in the database it just has 12 characters.
That's what is stored in the DB: [B@43e7be68

Here is the code of my SQL_INSERT:

```
public boolean SQL_INSERT_PICTURE(PictureDatatype type) {
    try{
        this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.d(TAG, "Insert picture");
        System.out.println("insert picture");
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM picture " +
                "where " + LinkPic + " = '" + type.getLink() + "'");
        db.execSQL("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO picture " +
                "( " + NamePic + ", " + LinkPic + ", " + PicturePic + ") " +
                "VALUES ('" + type.getName() + "', '" + type.getLink() +"', '" + 
                type.getPicture() +"')");

        System.out.println("size of the picture (bytearray): " + type.getPicture().length);
        System.out.println("the picture: " + type.getPicture());
        System.out.println("insert complete");
        db.close();
        return true;
    }
        catch(SQLException s){
            System.out.println("Insert failed");
            db.close();
            return false;
        }
}
```

my question is why isn't the correct byte[] stored in the DB or how can i do it?
If u need more information or code pls tell me.

thx
kirbby

Comment: just a side comment. you shouldnot save picture (BLOB) into your database because it will make CPU more intensive doing such task as translate binary back into media types :) why not just save your path to the picture to database

Comment: Side note: no need to DELETE the picture first if you're doing INSERT OR REPLACE anyway...

Comment: Also, assembling SQL statements using string concatenation is a sure-fire route to SQL injection exploits --- don't do this! Go look at the version of execSQL() that uses bound arguments; you can do `db.execSQL("DELETE FROM picture where LinkPic = ?", new Object[] { type.getLink() });`. It's faster, easier to read, and totally insulates you from SQL injection issues.

Comment: ok solved it. converted the pictures with Base64 to Strings and then saved the String in the DB and it works.
If u want i can post the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to convert the image to a ByteArray that can be stored as a BLOB:

```
    private byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // Middle value is quality, but PNG is lossless, so it's ignored.
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }
```

OR

```
    private byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
        final int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        final int height = bitmap.getHeight();
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(width * height * 4);

        bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
        return byteBuffer.array();
    }
```

First option should always work. Second option assumes 32bits-per-pixel (ARGB_8888 format) thus 4 bytes. if you're bitmap is of another format (e.g 565), it needs some modifications.

When you read the image data from the database, do it like this:

```
   public Bitmap loadIcon(long iconId) {
       // Prepare the cursor to read from database....
       byte[] bitmapData = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(Columns.Icons.DATA));

       return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapData, 0, bitmapData.length);
   }
```

Make sure that the the database is defined as BLOB when you execute your "create table" SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch, that looks like you're trying to pass a byte[] array into a string.

Assembling your SQL strings in this way is a very bad idea, for multiple reasons (security and performance).

See these two questions for prepared statements, and how to bind values to the statement without having to concatenate your SQL:

[insert a picture into database(sqlite) with java code. what should i do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182467/insert-a-picture-into-databasesqlite-with-java-code-what-should-i-do)

[Java Exception Error - Sqlite preparedStatement.setBlob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767968/java-exception-error-sqlite-preparedstatement-setblob)